# Get text from a program in Python

Tags: python, windows, text, request, notepad

I would like to get the text from a program with Python, for example from notepad. Can I "request" this text, just like from a website? I thought about something like this:

A document in Notepad:

```
Hello World!
This is a text!
```

GetText.py:

```
get_text("notepad.exe")
>>> Hello World!\nThis is a text!
```

Is this possible?

Comment: why don't you just read .txt file?

Comment: @Huy Maybe that particular .txt isn't saved at all?

Comment: Right, @Huy. Also, this is just so I know, how it works and so I can apply this method on other projects

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, not directly.

There are various accessibility, etc. APIs you could use to try and "read" the user interface of another program, but that's certainly a lot more involved than just a simple `get_text()` style call.

(And for Windows Notepad, you can enumerate the Notepad main window's child windows, find the edit/rich-text control it's using and send a WM_GETTEXT message (if my memory serves) and hope it sends you some of the current text back...)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in read-mode and simply print each line of the file using a for loop:

```
a_file = open('notepad.exe', 'r')
for line in a_file:
    print(line)

a_file.close() #Make sure you close whatever file you open
```

If you are using Jupyter Notebook, make sure notepad.exe is in the same directory as you have your notebook opened in.

Side note: If you have experience with the command line (e.g. Linux), you can also open it in a text editor like vim. There, you can more readily see and edit it.

Comment: Thanks, but that isnt the answer I was searching for. For example, when you have Whatsapp Web open, how can you read ALL the text printed on screen?

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry. I misinterpreted the question. Hmmmm.... Not sure there is a simple command to pull that one off.